# Street view goes to black in google maps

Tags: google-maps

My street view in google maps stopped working in a recent update.
It starts ok, and I can rotate the view, but when I move to another location I only get a black screen, and need to reenter googlemaps from the front page to get normal view again

Comment: What browser is this in? (I've been getting annoyed with Firefox over this). Does it look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1ppMN.png)?

Comment: Firefox, and it indeed looks like that. Wonderful, no?

Comment: I have been having this problem for a while and have tried the fixes [here](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18529?hl=en) to no avail. I haven't had this problem in browser like Chrome, so I suspect it could just be Google being evil (or not having ht latest version of flash, which in Firefox on Linux is difficult)... I will look for a solution anyway.

Comment: I think a solution to this might be to get Firefox to use the latest version of flash - *Note to potential answerer's - I will add [a bounty](http://askubuntu.com/help/bounty) to this question once the 2 day thing has passed.* - still working on it, this is weird...

Comment: ok... [I managed to get flash 14](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cR7I6.png) (with [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-fresh-player-plugin-in-ubuntu.html)) to run in Firefox 30 on Ubuntu 14.04... and it made absolutely no difference. google and their stupid stuff...

Comment: I've had similar issues with chrome on windows, and occasionally a notifcation about [WebGL hitting a snag](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/119154/permalink/google-maps-webgl.png).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the trouble. The problem went away when upgrading to the latest ubuntu. This gave some other trouble, like locking up somewhere in the display manager (!!!), but after some manual reinstallations this, too is 'sort of' over. I'm forcibly using the unity desktop now, but after a week of further tweaking I now have my four workspaces and most essential window manager functionality back. But where did the rest go? (No, don't try to answer that. --m10

Answer (score 10):

Go to "chrome://flags" in your browser. There, under **Experiments** enable "Override software rendering list" and enable the "Disable WebGL" option and relaunch the browser.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a solution to the problem, but more like a band-aid. If you click on the 
"?" help-bubble icon, you can select the option to use the classic Google maps. That seemed to work for me using Chrome on Linux -Version 36.0.1985.125 .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have the same problems. Seems to be a Google+Firefox problem.

Google has no "whitelisted" Firefox on Linux for the new Google Maps.

But you can force it using this link:
https://www.google.com/maps/preview/?force=webgl

Using that address I can see Street View without black screen!

You can read a little more here:
https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3031966?hl=en

Using this complete WebGL Google maps seems to work fine. A little slow compared with Chromium, but that's okay.

You can also «play» with the acceleration and WebGL settings from Firefox:
webgl.force-enabled
webgl.msaa-force
layers.acceleration.force-enabled

from about:config

I have an AMD/intel hybrid card on Dell 3450. But on AMD and Intel seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Chrome's hardware acceleration fixed this issue for me.

To do this [version 41.x]:

1. Go to Settings then scroll down and click Show advanced settings…
2. Scroll down further and look for the option Use hardware acceleration when available. Make sure the option is un-checked.
3. Reload your browser and that’s it. You can now see the black screen is already gone.

Link for a full walkthrough:
http://learn.yancyparedes.net/2014/08/fixing-google-maps-black-screen-display-on-google-chrome-running-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...